# Adding Free space to Container disk2

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

Is there a way to move (free space) and add it to Container disk2 in /dev/disk1

````
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *28.0 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         27.7 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         471.2 GB   disk1s2
                    (free space)                         528.8 GB   -

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +498.9 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Stores disk0s2, disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨MacOS Data⁩              93.4 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 285.5 MB   disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                652.6 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      2.1 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨MacOS BigSur⁩            22.7 GB    disk2s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 22.7 GB    disk2s5s1
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, The terminal command :

```
diskutil ap resizecontainer disk2 0b
```

will do the job ;-)